# I can't made maps in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-science

I'm currently creating my first data science project, I am using a Kaggle database called "COVID-19 World Vaccination Progress". And then I found myself in a problem.
I'm trying to make a map on plotly and unfortunately I can't mount it, even after several attempts. Can someone help me?

```
world_vaccines = df.groupby(['country','vaccines'])[['people_vaccinated']].max().reset_index()
fig = px.choropleth(world_vaccines, locations="iso_alpha",
                color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                hover_name="country",)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think choropleth only works with counties in the US

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is the information you're trying to plot is not available in `world_vaccines` or the [CSV](https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid-world-vaccination-progress) (`lifeExp` and `iso_alpha`).

To remedy this I modified the `groupby` statement to include `iso_code` and then used that for the `location` input and `people_vaccinated` as the `color` input (although other stats are available).

Here's a working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('country_vaccinations.csv')

world_vaccines = df.groupby(['iso_code','vaccines'])[['people_vaccinated']].max().reset_index()
fig = px.choropleth(world_vaccines, locations="iso_code",
                color="people_vaccinated",
                hover_name="iso_code",)
fig.show()
```

[image]